# How do I move an idea between communities?

Tags: administration, customer-portal, ideas

I have an org with a large number of communities, one of which is private. Some of the ideas posted in the private community need to be made public, while some need to stay private.

Based on this requirement I'm pretty sure my only option is to move the ideas that need to be public to one of the public communities, but this doesn't seem possible.

I should also note that these ideas do have votes and comments, so deleting and re-creating them in another community isn't particularly viable.

What options, if any, do I have for making these ideas publicly visible?

Comment: Is there a risk that users would make a comment in the private community that they wouldn't want exposed in the public one?

Comment: Yes, and some of the ideas in the private community themselves are inappropriate for the public portal.

Comment: Have you investigated writing a clone functionality which would clone records & vote records etc but change the communityId ? Combined with a manual selection process, this may work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the Ideas PM.

At the moment, we don't permit moving ideas between communities - simply because in most setups, all communities can't be accessed by all users.  Moving an idea could cause it to become invisible to the person who created it, or the people who commented and voted on it.

... would you care about this? Is it better to move the idea, and have it become invisible for those users?

Comment: Yes, I'd love to have that as an option. Sometimes there are ideas that were at one point sensitive (and private) and have since become less controversial that I'd like to make public. Likewise there are some good ideas that aren't appropriate for public consumption I'd like to make private (even if it removes the creator's visibility).

Comment: Also, full sharing model support (apex sharing reasons, etc.) as an option (so you could have "simplified visibility" vs "sharing model" on ideas?) would be amazing.